# Have to scroll UITableView to update cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently I am using an outlet of the imageView height constraint in order to adjust the height of the imageView like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object


 cell.productImageView.file = (PFFile *)object[@"image"];
        [cell.productImageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height / image.size.width * cell.cardView.frame.size.width;
            [cell.productImageView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];


            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
                [cell.cardView layoutIfNeeded];
            }];


        }];
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 350;
```

Is there a better way to change the height of the ImageView than to use a outlet to the height constraint?

I have to end up scrolling to have it update to the updated height constraint.

Comment: Just update your tableview in the main thread. You are recieving the data in the background. You should be update your UI elements in your main thread.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

reload your `tableView` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` something like this,

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.tableView reloadData];

  }
```

Comment: The image is downloaded in background. So this code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if your code is also resizing the cell based on image height. Inside the block where you update the imageView height constraint also put this code:

```
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
                if indexPath != nil {
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                }
```

**Objective C :**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
if (indexPath != nil) {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: objective c version?

Comment: @farhan Check my updated answer. I haven't verified the objective C code but it should be fine I guess.

Comment: Also just wondering, is using a height outlet like i am to update the height a efficient way of doing so?

Comment: Yes it's fine, if the constraints are breaking, then make the constraint less than or equal to and make the vertical content hugging/priority to 1000 for the imageView.

Answer (score 0):

You should only modify the UI on the main thread. This means that you should change your callback from this:

```
[cell.productImageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // code here
}];
```

to this, which uses Grand Central Dispatch to run on the main thread.

```
[cell.productImageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // code here. Will be run after dispatch_async returns. 
    });
}];
```

**Edit**:
This will be slow because `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and therefore `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:` are called whenever a cell scrolls into view. It is better to cache your images (both for performance and for your users’ mobile data). A built-in way to do this is [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html). To do this, add a property to your class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSCache *cache;
```

Then, in your `viewDidLoad`, create your cache:

```
self.cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
```

When you load an image in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:`, do something like this:

```
void (^updateView)(UIImage *) = ^(UIImage * _Nullable image) {
    cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height / image.size.width * cell.cardView.frame.size.width;
    [cell.productImageView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        [cell.cardView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

}];
UIImage *cached = [self.cache objectForKey:cell.productImageView.file];
if (cached) {
  cell.productImageView.image = cached;
  updateView(cached);
} else {
    [cell.productImageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self.cache setObject:image forKey:cell.productImageView.file];
        }
        updateView(image);
    }];
}
```

Comment: its alot more glitchy when scrolling

Comment: This is glitchy because you are loading the image every time the cell is scrolled into view. I would recommend caching. I will update my answer soon.